Solving a certain matrix equation
I am trying to solve the (real) matrix equation $X^{-1}AX=Y$, where the matrix
$A_{n\times n}$ is given and the matrices $X_{n\times n}, Y_{n\times n}$ are unknown matrices, with the only restriction that $Y$ is of the form $\begin{bmatrix} 
     S_{2\times 2} & T_{2\times (n-2)}\\\ \star & \star \end{bmatrix}$, where $S_{2\times 2}$ has equal row sums and $T_{2\times (n-2)}$ is consisted of two identical rows, i.e., $T_{2\times (n-2)}= \begin{bmatrix} 
     T_1\\\ T_1\end{bmatrix}$
(Thus we want $Y$ only to be of the given form and no restriction on $X$ except being invertible.) The thing is that I would like to solve this without diagonalising or triangularising $A$, i.e., no use of the eigenvalues of $A$, whatsoever.
I would very greatly appreciate it if you can direct me to some literature or give me some hints. I have a feeling that, even though we have only one rather weak restriction (i.e., the restriction on the form of $Y$), finding an explicit and "nice" solution is not possible. (When there is a solution.)

Just for the record: If one were to allow eigenvalue computations, then this can be approached as follows:
Rewrite as $AX - XY=0$. This is a Sylvester equation. A nontrivial solution $X≠0$ exists if an $A$ and $Y$ share an eigenvalue $λ$: in this case we can pick $X=uv^*$, where $u$ is a right eigenvector of $A$ and $v$ is a left eigenvector of $Y$ with respect to $λ$.
To get an invertible $X$, we need $n$ shared eigenvalues with linearly independent $u_k$ and $v_k$, in which case we can pick $$X=∑_k u_k v_k^*$$
So basically it boils down to constructing $Y$ so that it shares the eigenvalues of $A$, given the constraints.
